# Can anyone explain what's going on with the grid placement here? (Python Tkinter)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I've been trying to make a fitness-type program for practice and I'm just beginning to learn Tkinter and Python in general. What I'm currently struggling with is placing frames and widgets as I want them to and also make the program work within a single window(not creating new Tk() objects). Here's code:

```
from tkinter import *

SelectionSwitch = False
root = Tk()
root.minsize(width=800, height=600)
root.maxsize(width=800, height=600)

xrcslist = ['Pushup', 'Pullup', 'Boxjump', 'Squat', 'Wristcurl', 'Bicepcurl', 'Crunch', 'Lunge', 'Plank']
xrcslist.sort()

BasicFont = 'Calibri Bold'

TextStart = Label(root, height=3, text='Welcome', bg='#F2D7D2', fg='black', borderwidth=4, relief='groove', width=100)

ButtonStart = Button(root, width=25, height=4, text='Exercises', bg='#C70039', command=lambda: pressed())

frameSelection = Frame(root, bg='#DFF5DC', width=800, height=600) # frame on which all of the contents of Second Screen are placed

frameSpace1 = Frame(frameSelection, height=30, width=5, bg='blue') # intentionally made in blue color to see it(this is an empty frame simply to make a gap between the Label and Listbox)

frameSpace2 = Frame(frameSelection, height=280, width=5, bg='yellow') #intentionally made in yellow color to see it, but it seems like it's hidden behind the Listbox(this frame is supposed to separate two Listboxes, but it's not behaving as expected so I didn't add the second one yet)

frameSpace3 = Frame(frameSelection, height=30, width=5, bg='red') # intentionally made in red color to see it(another empty frame to separate listboxes from the button in the lower left corner)

ButtonBackSelection = Button(frameSelection, text='Back', width=15, height=4, command=lambda: main.YetAgain())

frameSelectionLists = Frame(frameSelection)

TextSelection = Label(frameSelection, width=100, height=3, text='Select exercises', bg='#F2D7D2', borderwidth=4, relief='groove')

lstbx1 = Listbox(frameSelection, width=17, height=8)
for i in xrcslist:
    lstbx1.insert(END, i)

scroll = Scrollbar(root, command=lstbx1.yview) # binding the scrollbar to the listbox

#configs
TextSelection.config(font=(BasicFont,11))
TextStart.config(font=(BasicFont, 11))

ButtonBackSelection.config(font=(BasicFont, 11))
ButtonStart.config(font=(BasicFont, 11))
lstbx1.config(yscrollcommand=scroll.set) 



class main(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        MainScreen()

    def YetAgain():
        global SelectionSwitch
        if SelectionSwitch == True: # this 'if' section checks if a window other than the first one is currently displayed
            frameSelection.grid_forget()
            SelectionSwitch = False
            MainScreen()
        else:
            MainScreen()


class Exercise(object):
    def __init__(self, type, musclegroup, calpersec, equipment):
        self.type = type
        self.musclegroup = musclegroup
        self.calpersec = calpersec
        self.equipment = equipment


def pressed(): # replaces the current window with the selection window when ButtonStart is pressed
    global SelectionSwitch
    SelectionSwitch = True
    TextStart.grid_forget()
    ButtonStart.grid_forget()
    frameSelection.grid()
    TextSelection.grid()
    frameSpace1.grid()
    lstbx1.grid(row=2,column=0)
    scroll.grid()
    scroll.place(in_=lstbx1, relx=1.0, relheight=1.0, bordermode="outside")
    frameSpace2.grid(row=2, column=1)
    frameSpace3.grid(row=3)
    ButtonBackSelection.grid(row=4)
    ButtonBackSelection.place(relx=0, rely=1, anchor=SW)


def MainScreen(): # window that is showed on launch
    TextStart.grid(row=0)
    ButtonStart.grid(row=1)
    ButtonStart.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)
    root.mainloop()



#list of exercises
Pushup = Exercise('hypertrophy', ['chest', 'triceps'], None, None)

Pullup = Exercise('hypertrophy', ['upper back','biceps'], None, 'pullup bar')

Boxjump = Exercise('hypertrophy', ['quads', 'glutes', 'hamstrings'], 0.16, 'box or an elevation')

Squat =  Exercise('hypertrophy', ['quads', 'glutes'], 0.15, None)

Wristcurl = Exercise('hypertrophy', ['forearms'], None, 'dumbbell or barbell')

Bicepcurl = Exercise('hypertrophy', ['biceps','brachialis','forearms'], None, 'dumbbell or barbell')

Crunch = Exercise('hypertrophy', ['abdominals', 'obliques'], 0.09, None)

Lunge = Exercise('hypertrophy',['quadriceps', 'glutes', 'hamstrings'], 0.1, None)

Plank = Exercise('hypertrophy', ['abdominals', 'lower back'], 0.05, None)


main()
```

Here's what happens when the program launches:

[image: Main Screen]

This part works just fine, I plan on adding stuff to it later.

When ButtonStart is pressed, however, something weird happens:

[image: Second Screen]

There are a few questions I have:

- Why is frameSelection not the size of root, even though it's dimensions are stated as 800x600, same as root?
- Why are widgets completely messed up on the second screen, even though I have assigned rows and columns where required(for TextSelection and frameSpace1 it doesn't matter, as I want them to go first and second anyway, I guess)?
- Would it be better to place widgets that are shown on launch on a frame instead of root directly? I've tried doing that and the positioning was all messy and non-responsive to `row`, `column`, `rowconfigure` and `columnconfigure`, just like the second screen.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that the `grid` and `pack` commands are designed to cause the containing widget to grow or shrink around its children. This is called *geometry propagation*. While this feature can be turned off, it is almost never a good idea to do so.

So, the first problem seems to be that you're not aware of this behavior. It doesn't matter if you give a frame a size. When you call `grid` on its children, the size of the frame will be ignored and the frame will grow or shrink to fit.

The second problem is that you're relying heavily on defaults when calling `grid`. As a rule of thumb you should *always* specify a row and a column. Otherwise, where the widget goes depends on the order in which it was added to the window.

Along the same line of thought, you are relying on the default value of the `sticky` option. You should also always specify a `sticky` option (unless you want the widget centered in its row and column) so that each widget uses the space allocated to it correctly. Without a `sticky` option, and because of the "shrink to fit" behavior, your frames are not filling the space that is given to them.

The third problem is that you aren't giving any rows or columns a `weight`. This controls how tkinter handles the case where there is more space than is necessary. Tkinter will allocate the extra space based on the `weight` of individual rows and columns. Rows and columns with a weight of zero (the default) will not receive any of the extra space. Another rule of thumb is that for any containing widget (typically a frame) that uses grid should *always* assign a positive weight to at least one row and one column.

> Would it be better to place widgets that are shown on launch on a frame instead of root directly?

Absolutely, yes. If you're wanting to swap out whole groups of widgets it is best to put all of those widgets in a frame. That way you only have to add or remove the one frame.

---

As an aside, you seem to be using `minsize` and `maxsize` to set the size of the window as a whole. A better way to do that is to use the `geometry` method of the window. For example:

```
root.geometry("800x600")
```

By using the `geometry` method you leave final control in the hands of the user. It also aids debugging, in that being able to resize the window helps you observe the behavior of the widgets: you can grow and shrink the window to verify your widgets are properly expanding or shrinking as you desire.

In your case, you should only be puttin frames directly in `root`. One for the startup widets, one for the widgets on the next screen, and so on.